# How to access views created in viewDivLoad

Tags: ios, swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBAction func button_down(_ sender: Any)
    {
        do_something(view: myView);
    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad();

        let screen_size: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds;
        var myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: screen_size.height/2 - screen_size.width/2, width: screen_size.width, height: screen_size.width));
        myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red;
        self.view.addSubview(myView);
    }
}
```

When I try to compile this code, I get an error:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'myView'
```

How can I solve this problem? I have tried declaring myView outside of viewDivLoad, but that's not permitted.

Comment: It's a concept called "variable scope". Basically, you cannot declare something - in this case a UIView called "myView" inside a function and reference it in a second one. You need to define the view in a broader scope than `viewDidLoad`. For instance, define it as an "instance variable" - inside your view controller but outside of any function, then remove the `var` in `viewDidLoad`. (FYI, you're making a few newbie mistakes like setting frames instead using auto layout. With your code, try running it on an iPhone 4s and an iPhone 7 plus. You'll see what I'm talking about.)

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely do some research on the concept of "scope" in computer programming - it'll be difficult to go too far without it. `myView` only exists within the scope of `viewDidLoad`. If you want it to be available outside of that, you can make it a property of the class like so:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    var myView: UIView!

    @IBAction func buttonDown(_ sender: Any)
    {
        doSomething(view: myView)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: screenSize.height/2 - screenSize.width/2, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.width))
        myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.view.addSubview(myView)
    }
}
```

A couple of other notes:

- You don't need semicolons at the end of lines in Swift.
- It seems you're using Interface Builder, so I would suggest creating `myView` that way instead of programmatically.
- Function and variable names in Swift should be camel cased - so `buttonDown` instead of `button_down`, `screenSize` instead of `screen_size`.